# Tornar um CSS responsivo

Tags: css, bootstrap, layout-responsivo

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema com Asp.Net Mvc utilizando o bootstrap, mas quero dar uma "carinha" diferente para a minha tela de login, criei um css mas gostaria de deixa-lo responsivo, alguém sabe como fazer isso? segue o CSS abaixo: mais especificamente o estilo "loginbox" (que é onde fica meu formulario de login)

```
    body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: url('../images/orage.png');
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

    .loginbox {
        width: 320px;
        height: 420px;
        background: #000;
        color: #fff;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        position: absolute;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        box-sizing: border-box;
        padding: 70px 30px;
        max-width: 100%;

    }



    .avatar {
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        position: absolute;
        top: -50px;
        left: calc(50% - 50px);
    }

    h1 {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0 0 20px;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 22px;
    }

    .login p {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        font-weight: bold;
    }

    .loginbox input {
        width: 100%;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
    }

    .footer {
        position: inherit;
        bottom: 0;
        width: 100%;
    }
```

Segue o Html

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form"  }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    ;

    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <br>
    <br>
    <div class="loginbox">

        <img src="~/images/avatar.png" class="avatar" />
        <h1>Login Here</h1>
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control input-lg", placeholder = "E-mail", autofocus = true } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })


        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Password, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control input-lg", placeholder = "Senha" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <input type="submit" value="Acessar" class="btn primary btn-lg" />
        <br/>
        <a href="#">Lost your password? </a>
        <a href="#"> Don't have an acount? </a>

    </div>
}
```

Imagem da tela de login[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Olha, existem diversas respostas para isso. Primeiro, anexe o seu html e nos dê um exemplo melhor de sua dúvida. Por dica, te aconselho a usar % nas alturas e larguras. Isso já ajuda UM POUCO.

Comment: Sem mais detalhes sua pergunta pode ser marcada como Duplicada ou até mesmo Fechada. Coloque mais precisamente como vc gostaria que ficasse (de preferencia com uma img). e não deixe de colocar o seu HTML tb!

Comment: Opa amigos, obrigado pelo toque, coloquei mais detalhes na pergunta

Comment: Você pode utilizar @media query do css para poder deixar seu elementos responsivos >> https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/CSS_Media_queries

Comment: Em vez de colocar o código que roda no servidor, coloque o HTML já renderizado pelo navegador. Facilita bastante já que o interesse é no HTML e CSS e não no código de programação.

Comment: Cara o seu .loginbox já está com 320px de largura, que é uma largura boa para smartphones etc. Quando vc fala que quer resposividade o que vc gostaria que mudasse e em quais tamanhos de tela? Vc quer que fique diferente no Tablet ou no Desktop por exemplo? Sem entender o que vc quer não tem como te dar uma resposta